# REST API database structure

Tags: rest, database-design, restful-architecture

Im building a simple REST Api, where i have "book" and "bookCategory".
They properities are very simple and the same:

```
book {id, name, created_at, modified_at }
bookCategory {id, name, created_at, modified_at }
```

If i had only this tables i would leave it like this, but i have the same logic and structure for "movie", "painting", "video games" etc.
Is it a good practice to split them into different table, even if they have the same structure, but logically they are different.
I could do this which saves me a lot of tables, controllers and forms (keep it DRY):

```
things {id, **parent_id**, name, created_at, modified_at, **type** }
```

*some example*

```
1 | 0 | "Comedy" | "movie"

2 | 1 | "Dumb and Dumber" | "movie"

3 | 1 | "Ace Ventura" | "movie"

4 | 0 | "Fantasy" | "book"

5 | 4 | "Lord of the Rings" | "book"
```

It is very compact, but how would look like an endpoint for "all movie categories" or "all categories" ?

```
domain/api/things/???
```

Or its better to lay down a flexible ground structure (maybe new properties will come)?

Answer (score 0):

Given the problem space as you've defined it, it's reasonable to use a vertical table - assuming you expect there will be no new properties which are unique to one entity (such as 'writer', which might be on book and movie, but not bookCategory or movieCategory). If you anticipate new unique properties (or aren't sure), I would suggest separate tables for each. While you're violating DRY now, the cost to change later is going to be large.

As far as endpoints,

```
GET /api/movieCategories
<- an entity with all movie categories
```

Again, if all categories have and will always have the same properties, it would be reasonable to instead do

```
GET /api/categories?type=movie
```